# Order by multiple columns in hibernate criteria

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

I have a table like below

```
    ID      creationDate        startDate       status      
    1       10-08-2019 08:00    10-08-2019 08:00    1   
    2       10-08-2019 07:00    10-08-2019 08:00    2
    3       10-08-2019 09:00    10-08-2019 08:00    2
    4       10-08-2019 08:00    10-08-2019 10:00    1
    5       10-08-2019 11:00    10-08-2019 08:00    2
```

I have written a code like below to fetch data by considering both dates and status. Finally I want to sort the result **by both creationDate and startDate** .

from = 09-08-2019 08:00

to = 11-08-2019 08:00

```
Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();
Conjunction creationDateConjunction = Restrictions.conjunction(); 
creationDateConjunction.add(Restrictions.in("status", 2));
creationDateConjunction.add(between("creationDate", from, to));

Conjunction startDateConjunction = Restrictions.conjunction();
startDateConjunction.add(Restrictions.in("status",1));
startDateConjunction.add(between("startDate", from, to));

disjunction.add(creationDateConjunction);
disjunction.add(startDateConjunction);
criteria.add(disjunction);
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("creationDate"));
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("startDate"));
```

I am getting results (IDs) as 
**2,3,5,1,4** (First order by createDate then startDate)

But I want to get 
**2,1,3,4,5** (As time getting increase)

Can some one help me to write a query to get correct order

Comment: Can you show the SQL statement being generated by this code?

Comment: Your code does not work as you want to pick the sorting key depending on another column. I would try to select a new, computed value with a case statement, give it an alias and order by this column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your query to predicates and add required sort order.

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/jpa-2-0-criteria-query-with-hibernate.html

[How to order result of hibernate based on a specific order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281162/how-to-order-result-of-hibernate-based-on-a-specific-order)